# Why does my Samsung A42 delete photos off my phone at the end of the day?

Tags: samsung, photos, gallery, delete

I recently purchased a Samsung A42 and when I take photos and videos, they are on the Gallery that day, but the next morning they have been removed.  They are auto-backed up to Google Photos, but I'm not using Verizon or Samsung Cloud.  I've looked through other forums and the settings in Google Photos and Gallery to make sure there is NOT a setting selected to automatically remove the photos after back up.  If I download a picture, it goes to the "Downloads" or "Restored" albums in Gallery and those don't get removed. Confused...thanks!

Comment: Check the settings in the Samsung Gallery App, not just Google Photos.  They could be fighting each other.

Comment: By the way, the removed photos do NOT appear in the Gallery trash or under "recent" in the Gallery either.